# Issue with Selenium Java application on Linux server: downloads not working as expected

Tags: java, linux, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have a Java Selenium application running on a Linux server. The application is supposed to click a button and download a file to a directory that I have specified. However, even though the clicking action is performed successfully, the downloaded file doesn't appear in the designated directory. I'm wondering if it's not downloading at all or if it's being saved in a different location that I'm unaware of. Can someone please assist me with this issue?

```
HashMap<String, Object> chromePrefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
chromePrefs.put("download.default_directory", directoryPath);
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromePrefs);

String chromeDriverPath = "/usr/bin/chromedriver";
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", chromeDriverPath);
options.addArguments("--headless");
options.addArguments("window-size=1920,1080");
```

Any insights or suggestions on what might be causing this problem would be greatly appreciated.

The application is running successfully locally. It also clicks the download button without throwing any errors. However, it's not downloading the file to the directory I specified or any other visible directory.

Comment: After the last Chrome update, I noticed that when a file download starts, Chrome asks for path and filename, even if the preference is not to ask for folder when downloading.. I've got the issue on Selenium with Python in OSX